# How to handle foreach inside foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to follow the concept of "DRY" So I have a lot of repetition in my code. decided to make it short as I can!

The design that I need to reach is: 
[image]

my shut:

```
   @php
        $names = [
            'main','settings', 'admins','roles'
        ];
        $values = [
            'main_page','setting','admin','role'
        ];
    @endphp

    @foreach ($names as $name)
        <main class="role_me">
                -- {{ $name }}
            <div class="roles">
                @foreach ($values as $value)
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $value}}_read">Read</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $value}}_create">Create</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $value}}_update">Update</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $value}}_delete">Delete</label>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </main>
    @endforeach
```

The output of my code is:

[image]

Comment: HTML would be much more useful than pictures. None of your code seems to line up with your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we require two loops to display those menu and their sub menus. Try this

```
$action = ["Edit", "Read", "Delete", "Add"];

$categories = ["Menu", "Roles", "Users"];

for($i = 0; $i < count($categories); $i++) {
    echo $categories[$i]. "<br>";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($action); $j++) {
       echo $categories[$i]. " " .$action[$j] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Output like this.

```
Menu
Menu Edit
Menu Read
Menu Delete
Menu Add
Roles
Roles Edit
Roles Read
Roles Delete
Roles Add
Users
Users Edit
Users Read
Users Delete
Users Add
```